# How to use javascript variables with django or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

I am trying to generate random numbers between 1 to 132 (inclusive) using JavaScript, when a user clicks on a button.

So far so good, it generates the value and I am able to get the desired output.

**The problem:**
I was to use the generated value in a custom Django filter (or whatever it is called). Let me explain it better with my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function random_generator()
    {
      var rand = [];
      var i;
      var j;
      var text = "";
      for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      {
        rand[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 132) + 1);
        text += rand[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('rand1').innerHTML = text; //Just trying to see if the numbers are generated properly

      var text2 = "{%for i in allb %}{%if i.id == " + text + "|add:0 %}<p>{{ i.name }}</p>{% endif %}{%endfor%}";
      document.getElementById('rand2').innerHTML = text2;
      document.writeln(rand[0]);
    }
  </script>
```

Here's what else I tried doing:

```
<div id="b005" class="modal">
    <div id="rand1"></div>
    <div id="rand2"></div>
      {%for i in allb %}
        {%if i.id == **WANT TO USE THE JS VARIABLE HERE**|add:0 %}
          <p>{{ i.name }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      {%endfor%}
  </div>
```

**Note:**`allb` is an object that I have passed from my views.py

Is there any other way of doing the same?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This question is based on a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between frontend and backend code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel already mentioned, you have to first understand what is going on behind the scenes. Your django templates only exist on your server, and all template code gets executed on that server. This template code can be used for non-html rendering as well, as you are doing in your random_generator() script.

But the browser receives only an evaluated version of the templates. So it is impossible to compare your django template code (server-side) to your client-side js.